# Returning from function containing promise.all

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am using the async code below to fetch an array of urls, once all the urls are fetched and added to the object mapGeometry. I need to return mapGeometry from the function returnMapGeometry hence all the code needs to pause until I do.

I am having a lot of trouble getting the syntax right, how can I return mapGeometry once all the fetches have resolved and each mapGeometryPiece has been added to mapGeometry?

```
function returnMapGeometry() {
  var mapGeometry = new THREE.Group();

  Promise.all(
    urls.map((url, index) => fetch(new Request(url))
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => doSomeWork(URL.createObjectURL(blob))
        .then(mapGeometryPiece => {
          mapGeometry.add(mapGeometryPiece)
        })
      ))
  }
  // code must pause until returnMapGeometry() returns

  mapGeometry = returnMapGeometry()
```

NOTE: mapGeometry is a Three.js group - I dont think that this makes any difference see: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Group

Comment: `code must pause` - javascript is the wrong language if you want to pause

Comment: Return promise from `Promise.all()`.  Caller uses `.then()` on the promise to get results.  There is no pausing in Javascript.  Must learn async programming.

Comment: I mean, the code in the question doesn't even PARSE ... so, how can you expect it to do anything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to chain and return a `.then` on the `Promise.all` that resolves with the `mapGeometry` you've constructed, and then when you call `returnMapGeometry`, it will resolve with the `mapGeometry`. Because it needs to return a `Promise` and not the actual `mapGeometry`, it would make more sense to call the function something slightly different, perhaps `getMapGeometry`.

You can also remove the unnecessarily nested `.then` on `doSomeWork` so as to make the code flatter:

```
function getMapGeometry() {
  var mapGeometry = new THREE.Group();

  return Promise.all(
    urls.map((url, index) => fetch(new Request(url))
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => doSomeWork(URL.createObjectURL(blob))
      .then(mapGeometryPiece => mapGeometry.add(mapGeometryPiece))
    ))
  )
    .then(() => mapGeometry);
  // code must pause until returnMapGeometry() returns
}
getMapGeometry()
  .then((mapGeometry) => {
    // do stuff with mapGeometry
  });
```